# Grouping by rows in column

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have an angular web app that is working, properly and now I am tidying it up a bit. Here is what it looks like: [image]

I would like to group the rows in the Team column to just show once. For example, on the image above there are three rows of gold one. I would like to only have one row that has the same height as three gold ones. I only want to group in that column. Just in case my text explanation isn't clear enough, here is an image of what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

I've searched all over stack overflow for an angular example like mine, but I cannot find anything. Can someone please help me?

Here is my code for my app:

### Index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="app.css" />
      <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/domo.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>      
  </head>
  <body ng-app="rcr_sched" ng-controller="main">
      <div id="mydiv">
        <table>
            <tr id="printc"><button id="print" class="fa fa-print fa-3x" onclick="print('#mydiv')"></button>
            <button id="print2" onclick="print('#mydiv')">Print Page</button>
            </tr>
            <tr height="40" id="header">
                <th ng-repeat="prop in columns">{{prop.date}}</th>
            </tr>  
            <tr ng-repeat="r in data">
                <td align="center" ng-repeat="prop2 in columns" class="{{getColor(r.TeamRank, r.Team, prop2.title)}}" style="{{isPTO(prop2.title, 'PTO' + prop2.title, r['PTO' + prop2.title])}}">
                    {{r[prop2.title]}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
      </div>      
  </body>
</html>
```

### App.js

```
var app = angular.module('rcr_sched',['ngRoute']);

 app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
       .when('/',{
           templateUrl:'index.html',
           controller:'main'
       })
       .when('drill',{
           templateUrl:'drill.html'
       })
//       .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});  
    }
 ]);
//Range Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

app.controller('main', ['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location){
        $scope.goNext = function(view){
            $location.path('/');
        }
        $scope.data = [];
        $scope.columns = [];
        $scope.currentDate = new Date();
        $scope.calculateDate = function() {
            var x = new Date();
            return {
                'MonThisWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() - (x.getDay() - 1)), title:'MonThisWk'},
                'TueThisWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() - (x.getDay() - 2)),title:'TueThisWk'},
                'WedThisWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() - (x.getDay() - 3)),title:'WedThisWk'},
                'ThuThisWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() - (x.getDay() - 4)),title:'ThuThisWk'},
                'FriThisWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() - (x.getDay() - 5)),title:'FriThisWk'},
                'MonNextWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 7 - (x.getDay() - 1)),title:'MonNextWk'},
                'TueNextWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 7 - (x.getDay() - 2)),title:'TueNextWk'},
                'WedNextWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 7 - (x.getDay() - 3)),title:'WedNextWk'},
                'ThuNextWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 7 - (x.getDay() - 4)),title:'ThuNextWk'},
                'FriNextWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 7 - (x.getDay() - 5)),title:'FriNextWk'},
                'Mon2Wks': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 14 - (x.getDay() - 1)),title:'Mon2Wks'},
                'Tue2Wks': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 14 - (x.getDay() - 2)),title:'Tue2Wks'},
                'Wed2Wks': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 14 - (x.getDay() - 3)),title:'Wed2Wks'},
                'Thu2Wks': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 14 - (x.getDay() - 4)),title:'Thu2Wks'},
                'Fri2Wks': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 14 - (x.getDay() - 5)), title:'Fri2Wks'}
            }
        }
        $scope.isPTO = function(rowTitle, ptoTitle, value) {
            if (rowTitle == (ptoTitle.replace('PTO', '')) && value) {
                return 'background-color: #32CD32;';
            }
            return '';
        }

        function print(elem){
            Popup($('<div/>').append($(elem).clone()).html());
        }

        function Popup(data) 
{
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=400,width=600');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
    mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ddincludes/mainstyle.css" type="text/css" />');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body>');
    mywindow.document.write(data);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');


    mywindow.print();
  //  mywindow.close();
    return true;
}

        $scope.dateOptions = $scope.calculateDate();
        $scope.getColor = function(teamRank, team, prop) {
            let today = new Date();

            if (prop == 'Team' || prop == 'TeamMember') 
            {
                if (team == 'Unassigned') 
                {
                    return "grayClass";
                }
                else if (team == 'Gold One') 
                {
                    return "goldClass";
                }
                else if (team == 'Red One' || team == 'Red Two') 
                {
                    return "redClass";
                }
                else if (team == 'Blue One' || team == 'Blue Two') {
                    return "blueClass"
                }
                else if (team == 'Green One') 
                {
                    return "greenClass";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "grayClass";
                }
            }
            if(prop == 'MonThisWk' || prop == 'Mon2Wks')
           {
               if(today.getDay() == 1)
               {
                    return "highlightClass";   
               } 
           }
           if(prop == 'TueThisWk' || prop == 'Tue2Wks')
           {
               if(today.getDay() == 2)
               {
                    return "highlightClass";   
               }
           }
           if(prop == 'WedThisWk' || prop == 'Wed2Wks')
           {
               if(today.getDay() == 3)
               {
                    return "highlightClass";   
               }
           }
           if(prop == 'ThuThisWk' || prop == 'Thu2Wks')
           {
               if(today.getDay() == 4)
               {
                    return "highlightClass";   
               }
           }
            if(prop == 'FriThisWk' || prop == 'Fri2Wks')
           {
               if(today.getDay() == 5)
               {
                    return "highlightClass";   
               }
           }

        }

        domo.get('data/v1/master?fields=Team,TeamMember,TotalJobs,NDD,Past,MonThisWk,TueThisWk,WedThisWk,ThuThisWk,FriThisWk,MonNextWk,TueNextWk,WedNextWk,ThuNextWk,FriNextWk,Mon2Wks,Tue2Wks,Wed2Wks,Thu2Wks,Fri2Wks,FutureDates,PTOMonThisWk,PTOTueThisWk,PTOWedThisWk,PTOThuThisWk,PTOFriThisWk,PTOMon2Wks,PTOTue2Wks,PTOWed2Wks,PTOThu2Wks,PTOFri2Wks,PTOMonNextWk,PTOTueNextWk,PTOWedNextWk,PTOThuNextWk,PTOFriNextWk,HolMonThisWk,HolTueThisWk,HolWedThisWk,HolThuThisWk,HolFriThisWk,HolMonNextWk,HolTueNextWk,HolWedNextWk,HolThuNextWk,HolFriNextWk,HolMon2Wks,HolTue2Wks,HolWed2Wks,HolThu2Wks,HolFri2Wks&groupby=TeamRank,Team,TeamMember&orderby=TeamRank')
            .then(function(data){
                $scope.data = data;
                for (prop in data[0]) {
                    if ($scope.dateOptions[prop]) {
                        var newDate = $scope.dateOptions[prop];
                        var formattedProp = {date: (newDate.date.getMonth() + 1).toString() + '/' + newDate.date.getDate().toString(), title: newDate.title};
                    }
                    else {
                        var formattedProp = {date: prop, title: prop};
                    }
                    $scope.columns.push(formattedProp);
                }
                $scope.$apply();
            })
    }]);

app.controller('drill', ['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location){
        $scope.goNext = function(view){
            $location.path('drill');
        }
        $scope.data = [];
        $scope.columns = [];
        $scope.currentDate = new Date();
        $scope.calculateDate = function() {
            var x = new Date();
            return {
                'MonThisWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() - (x.getDay() - 1)), title:'MonThisWk'},
                'TueThisWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() - (x.getDay() - 2)),title:'TueThisWk'},
                'WedThisWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() - (x.getDay() - 3)),title:'WedThisWk'},
                'ThuThisWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() - (x.getDay() - 4)),title:'ThuThisWk'},
                'FriThisWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() - (x.getDay() - 5)),title:'FriThisWk'},
                'MonNextWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 7 - (x.getDay() - 1)),title:'MonNextWk'},
                'TueNextWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 7 - (x.getDay() - 2)),title:'TueNextWk'},
                'WedNextWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 7 - (x.getDay() - 3)),title:'WedNextWk'},
                'ThuNextWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 7 - (x.getDay() - 4)),title:'ThuNextWk'},
                'FriNextWk': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 7 - (x.getDay() - 5)),title:'FriNextWk'},
                'Mon2Wks': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 14 - (x.getDay() - 1)),title:'Mon2Wks'},
                'Tue2Wks': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 14 - (x.getDay() - 2)),title:'Tue2Wks'},
                'Wed2Wks': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 14 - (x.getDay() - 3)),title:'Wed2Wks'},
                'Thu2Wks': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 14 - (x.getDay() - 4)),title:'Thu2Wks'},
                'Fri2Wks': {date: new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getMonth(), x.getDate() + 14 - (x.getDay() - 5)), title:'Fri2Wks'}
            }
        }
        $scope.isPTO = function(rowTitle, ptoTitle, value) {
            if (rowTitle == (ptoTitle.replace('PTO', '')) && value) {
                return 'background-color: #32CD32;';
            }
            return '';
        }

        function print(elem){
            Popup($('<div/>').append($(elem).clone()).html());
        }

        function Popup(data) 
{
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=400,width=600');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
    mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ddincludes/mainstyle.css" type="text/css" />');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body>');
    mywindow.document.write(data);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');


    mywindow.print();
  //  mywindow.close();
    return true;
}

        $scope.dateOptions = $scope.calculateDate();
        $scope.getColor = function(teamRank, team, prop) {
            let today = new Date();

            if (prop == 'Team' || prop == 'TeamMember') 
            {
                if (team == 'Unassigned') 
                {
                    return "grayClass";
                }
                else if (team == 'Gold One') 
                {
                    return "goldClass";
                }
                else if (team == 'Red One' || team == 'Red Two') 
                {
                    return "redClass";
                }
                else if (team == 'Blue One' || team == 'Blue Two') {
                    return "blueClass"
                }
                else if (team == 'Green One') 
                {
                    return "greenClass";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "grayClass";
                }
            }
            if(prop == 'MonThisWk' || prop == 'Mon2Wks')
           {
               if(today.getDay() == 1)
               {
                    return "highlightClass";   
               } 
           }
           if(prop == 'TueThisWk' || prop == 'Tue2Wks')
           {
               if(today.getDay() == 2)
               {
                    return "highlightClass";   
               }
           }
           if(prop == 'WedThisWk' || prop == 'Wed2Wks')
           {
               if(today.getDay() == 3)
               {
                    return "highlightClass";   
               }
           }
           if(prop == 'ThuThisWk' || prop == 'Thu2Wks')
           {
               if(today.getDay() == 4)
               {
                    return "highlightClass";   
               }
           }
            if(prop == 'FriThisWk' || prop == 'Fri2Wks')
           {
               if(today.getDay() == 5)
               {
                    return "highlightClass";   
               }
           }

        }

        domo.get('data/v1/master?fields=Team,TeamMember,JobNumber&groupby=TeamRank,Team,TeamMember&orderby=TeamRank')
            .then(function(data){
                $scope.data = data;
                for (prop in data[0]) {
                    if ($scope.dateOptions[prop]) {
                        var newDate = $scope.dateOptions[prop];
                        var formattedProp = {date: (newDate.date.getMonth() + 1).toString() + '/' + newDate.date.getDate().toString(), title: newDate.title};
                    }
                    else {
                        var formattedProp = {date: prop, title: prop};
                    }
                    $scope.columns.push(formattedProp);
                }
                $scope.$apply();
            })
    }]);
```

### App.css

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: xx-small;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    -moz-print-color-adjust: exact;
}

a{
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 15px
}

table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th{
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

td{
    border: 2px solid white;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

/*
table, th, td {
    border: 2px solid white;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;

}
*/

td{
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
}

.redClass {
    background-color: #ffbbb3;
}

.blueClass {
    background-color: #b3d1ff;
}

.grayClass {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
}

.goldClass {
    background-color: #efe68f;
}

.greenClass {
    background-color: #b0e89f;
}

.ptoClass {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}

.highlightClass {
    background-color: #FEF65B;
}


.hideClass {
    background-color: white;
    color: white;
}
#header{
    background-color: #c9c9c9;
}

#print{
    background-color: white;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    border: none;
}

#print2{
    border: none;
    background-color: white;
    align-content: right;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;

}

td:nth-child(1){
    border-left-color: #2F4F4F;
}
td:nth-child(2){
    border-right-color: #2F4F4F;
}
td:nth-child(3){
    border-right-color: #2F4F4F;
}
td:nth-child(4){
    border-right-color: #2F4F4F;
}
td:nth-child(9){
    border-right-color: #2F4F4F;
}
td:nth-child(14){
    border-right-color: #2F4F4F;
}
td:nth-child(19){
    border-right-color: #2F4F4F;
}

td:nth-child(20){
    border-right-color: #2F4F4F; 
}
th:nth-child(n+21){
    display: none;
}

td:nth-child(n+21) {
    display: none;    
}


@media print{
    #print{
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    #print2{
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    #link{
        display: none;
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think I'm going to be of much help myself, but what you looking for sounds like "Grouping View" if you search for that, you may be able to find what you looking for.

Comment: Thank you, i'll check it out!